# Notepad++: Regex issue

Tags: notepad++, regex

## What I'm trying to do is

to remove all line numbers. In other words to find and replace all expressions like `x:` or `xx:` with  :

[image]

## Tried:

[image]

**No success!**

Also

[image]

**No success!**

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564454/regex-to-replace-all-numbers-and-special-chars-with-empty-spaces) what you're looking for?

Comment: This is the sort of thing you can do by holding ctrl+alt while you select text in Notepad++: http://imgur.com/DMDoC. It takes a couple of gos when you have more digits, but it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]+:
```

You should not put quote characters in the regexp.

Comment: `^([0-9]+)\:\s` helped me

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression: `[0-9:]+  *`.